# Is there any way to improve the animation when the view changes in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-3

Every 200 milliseconds, I'm changing the view of my map.

I'm changing the lon/lat values of the view's center by adding 50 meters.

Here is the jsfiddle and my function I use to set the view: "https://jsfiddle.net/salmanb1/14hke7k1/16/"

```
function animate(){

    centerPoint[0] = centerPoint[0] + 50;
    centerPoint[1] = centerPoint[1] + 50;

    proj_view.setCenter(centerPoint);

    render();
```

As one can see, the view has a jittery effect when it changes.

Is there any way to change the view smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Animation example in OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html), which should give you ideas how to improve the animation you're trying to do.

Comment: I've looked at that example and the example shows animation for just one particular time from point A to point B.
I'm looking at the animation that will continuously take place over multiple points.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snip to see if feet to your expected behaviour. Instead of setting the new center , you ask for animate to the new center

```
function animate(){

        centerPoint[0] = centerPoint[0] + 50;
        centerPoint[1] = centerPoint[1] + 50;
        proj_view.animate({zoom: proj_view.getZoom()}, {center: centerPoint});

}
```

There are several options to use in order to adjust the animation -->
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#animate

Comment: I've tried using .animate method as well but the animation still has a jittery effect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/6pczzytv/ . Is this what you look for? For my self it is very smooth and I dont think you ar going to get something better.

Comment: Do you think there's any way to make it smooth without adding 500 to the center point?
In my app, I can only add 21 to the center point

Comment: If you zoom in more yes it is. If you keep your current zoom level its worth trying. Just think about it logically

Comment: What do you think causes the jitter? It seems to be very noticeable when both latitude and longitude values are changed.

Comment: You need to find the best combination of animation delay and the setInterval threshold. Also if you change your center just a few meters and you are in a low zoom level there is not serious visual impact of the animation. For example in zoom level 10 a few meters change is lets say 5 pixel while on zoom level 2 is 100 pixel.